# How to install React Native dependencies inside the iOS project?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, git-submodules

I have integrated React Native into an already existing iOS app, and everything is working as expected: connecting to the Metro server or to the local `main.jsbundle` file.

We have used Git submodules to contain the iOS and Android apps (sub-repositories) inside the React Native app (main repository). So Android and iOS teams can work separately in our own branches.

But we would also like when somebody clones the iOS repo standalone to be able to run the app without having to download the parent React Native repository.

Currently, this is not possible (even though we are not connecting to the Metro server but to the `main.jsbundle` file that is included in the iOS repo) for the following reason.

> require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
> require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
> The Podfile accesses the parent folder (React Native repo), where the React Native libraries are located. Instead of obtaining them from the iOS project itself. This makes CocoaPods installation impossible outside the React Native app context/repo.

Is there a way to install React Native libraries and dependencies inside the iOS project without forcing CocoaPods to look for them outside?